# Site/Page permissions based on FBA roles

Tags: 2013, permissions, forms-authentication, access, denied

I've setup FBA for SharePoint 2013.

I need that only users that have a specific FBA role be able to access to a specific Page.

I tried:
- Adding a FBA role into a Site Group and give permissions to that group in the page.An access denied is the result.
- Adding permissions directly to the FBA role. Same error.

The only way the users are able to access to page is giving permissions directly to them.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating a SP group and then adding the FBA users to that group? That's how I'd do it. You can then use the SP group to assign permissions.

Comment: Thank for the prompt reply! Yes,it works. But doing it, the use of FBA roles loses meaning, at least in my case. I thought that maybe there is a chance to map 1 to 1 the Roles to the SP Groups.

Comment: Check out this post also. Seems like you can add FBA roles to SP Groups.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30301/add-fba-role-to-sharepoint-2010-group

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604542/fba-user-in-fba-role-is-not-taking-permission-from-sharepoint-group